# mysql replication - slave server on one database

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

I couldn't find an answer to my question.

I have 2 mysql servers.

1. Master server
2. Slave server

Now i want to add another Slave server but i have other website running on that server.

Can i replicate just one database?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes you can

If you want to replicate just one database from master, you can set `replicate-do-db` in your `/etc/my.cnf` or set `replicate-do-db` as mysql argument, for example:

```
replicate-do-db=db01
```

If you have multi databases to be replicated, `/etc/my.cnf` should be like this:

```
replicate-do-db=db01
replicate-do-db=db02
```

If you just want slave to ignore some database, you can set `replicate-ignore-db`:

```
replicate-ignore-db=db01
```

More details on MySQL document: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-db

Answer (score 3):

Adding these lines to the /etc/my.conf file of the slave machine solved my problem. Thanks.

```
replicate-do-db=Refill
```

However, please note that after doing this i had to restart both the databases and update the new file name and position from the master server by typing below command:

```
mysql> show master status;
```

Add this information to your MySQL on slave machine and start slave.