# MariaDB: Slave with single mirror DB and multiple local DB

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb, firewall, database-replication

I am using CentOS 7 with `MariaDB-5.5.47`. I wish to have two servers, master, which is inside firewall and the slave is outside firewall. Slave shall connect to master via SSH tunnel (see [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-mysql-replication-using-ssh-on-a-vps)). The firewall allows only slave to connect from outside on the tunneling port, and no one/nothing else.

Slave requires only a single database from master (say DB1) as read-only, nothing else. I verified that this could be done (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605318/mysql-replication-slave-server-on-one-database)).

What I require is that slave should have other databases besides the one being replicated from master. Could this be achieved or will mirroring will force slave to have only DB1 database?

Comment: Contrast the `binlog_do_*` and `replicate_do_*` settings in my.cnf.  I don't understand your question, but that might get you to the answer.